# What is the purpose of IsLocalUrl?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am bit confused about the usage of IsLocalUrl from Security perspective. Does it have any usage other than avoiding Open Redirection Attacks? Is there any relation of this with CDN based applications?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this utility determines whether the URL is a local URL (non-absolute URL) like "Customers/Index", or an absolute URL like "www.site.com/Customers/Index" ([see MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.islocalurl?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)).  There are some interesting boundaries when it detects local vs non-local so research those.

The [ASP.NET Core documentation of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.islocalurl?view=aspnetcore-2.2) was clearer in intent (and I'm assuming implemented the same or similar way).  I didn't realize "../" notation was non-local.

Comment: I am mainly looking for the use cases for IsLocalUrl to prevent real world hacking scenarios

Comment: See this as an example of such: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks

Comment: The main idea is if you have a known URL, you can check it to ensure a URL is not redirecting out of the site, either by manipulating a return URL like the example above, or a URL in the database, etc.